# Schema for logging music stream events

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql

I have a music application with albums, playlists, and songs. I would like to be able to track streaming events (like plays) by user and stream location (album or playlist).

For example songs can be placed in both albums and playlists, so when a user clicks "play" on the track I want to log where the song was played from (`playlistId` or `albumId`), who clicked play (`userId`), and when this event occurred (`timestamp`). In the future I may want to log more `eventTypes` like: play, pause, resume

My first thought was to have the following table:

```
Events
-----
id: Int (pk)
userId: Int
trackId: Int
albumId: Int
playlistId: Int
eventType: String (ex: play, pause)
timestamp: DateTime
```

However, either the `playlistId` or `albumId` would be null on each row because the song can only be streamed from one location at a time. So my next thought would be to break Events up in to their respective locations: `PlaylistEvents` and `AlbumEvents` which would contain the exact same properties except for `albumId` in the `PlaylistEvents` and `playlistId` in the `AlbumEvents` table. Which would mean I'm duplicating properties.

I was curious what some suggestions would be for a database schema to track events like this? I have a SQL database, but would something like a NoSQL database for tracking events be more effective as I continue to build out what other events I might want to track in the future?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: "However, either the `playlistId` or `albumId` would be null" -- And what would be the problem with that?

Comment: @stickybit currently not an issue but would just be useless for some rows, I'm just curious if there is a better way to think about event tracking!